# Android: How to create horizontal listview using listview / gridview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-gridview, android-pageradapter

Please provide solution without using view pager element.
Please mention all the sources used in the solution - including the links to external libraries (if used).

Comment: you can use horizontalscrollview and make the custom listview in it.

Comment: why dont you use recycler view ?

Comment: try [recent-images](https://github.com/amirarcane/recent-images) gridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Support Library of the Android has a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html#RecyclerView) that does exactly what you want.

this [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidRecyclerView/article.html) explains RecyclerView in detail.

You can read the documentation [here.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)

The source code for horizontal listview is: using RecyclerView

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
    = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

RecyclerView myList = findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
myList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Comment: Nice to hear that :-)

Answer (score 0):

ListView is now became old one. I recommend you RecyclerView instead.

With `RecyclerView` you can make Horizontal List easily.

```
RecyclerView yourRecyclerView;//make your RecylclerView
YourRecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter;//make your adapter with extends RecyclerView.Adapter<YourRecyclerViewAdapter.YourViewHolder>

if (isGridLayout) {
        mHorizontalGridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(mContext,2,GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
        yourRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mHorizontalGridLayoutManager);
        yourRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
} else {
        mHorizontalLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        yourRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mHorizontalLinearLayoutManager);
        yourRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```